# Automate Azure Deployment

Tags: azure, deployment, automation

I'm trying to understand the automation deployment options existing in Azure. I wanted to build a simple description of some components, similar to the Wordpress Template available in the Marketplace, something that doesn't need command line to run.

So far I've seen different approaches using PowerShell, CLI and even one API. I didn't quite understand them, can someone help me understand the different options available? And my main problem, how to build a command line free template for Azure, like the ones available in the Marketplace (any tutorial?).

Thanks.

Comment: the 'different approaches' part is an interesting question. But it isn't entirely clear what your first paragraph is looking for. 'simple description of some of the components'? can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Hello @MichaelB , my main goal is to find a way to develop a command line free template for azure. My secondary goal to get a list of ways of automate deployment in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should understand that there are 2 different deployment models in Azure:

1. Service Management model (ASM, IaaSv1, PaaSv1) or classic deployment model.
2. Resource Manager (ARM, IaaSv2, PaaSv2) deployement model.

Details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-deployment-model/

Different models and different approaches but Azure Resource Manager gives us a possibility to use JSON templates to deploy the content of entire Resource Group by only one click/command (so, 1 JSON files can describe 1 Resource Group). Please, play with following OpenSource projects to understand more:

- Visual Tool for ARM Templates : http://armviz.io/
- A lot of examples including some Marketplace resources https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates

Ability to export templates from Azure is comming ( https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/7163577-ability-to-export-a-resource-group-as-a-template )

As you have noticed there are many possibilities to deploy templates :

- PowerShell/CLI scripts
- API and Azure Portal (Template Deployment)
- Visual Studio (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools)

I think, the course "Azure Resource Manager DevOps Jump Start" ( https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/azure-resource-manager-devops-jump-start-8413 ) can help you.